# Passing multiple strings from one class to another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iPhone. I have small doubt. I have three strings in class BiblePlayerViewController and I want to pass those 3 strings to appdelegate from this class. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

create a property NSDictionary in BiblePlayerViewController and add your three strings to the dictionary,so you can read that dictionary where ever you want

```
NSDictionary *FileDict = [[NSDictionary  alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:str1,@"key1",str2,@"key2",str3,@"key3",nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable of type `NSString` in `appdelegate.h`

```
NSString *test;
```

import `appdelegate.h` in `BiblePlayerViewController.m`
 Now get a reference to appdelegate class using

```
Appdelegate *ad; //init with some object
 //now access the NSString var u just created
 ad.test=@"your string";
```

Comment: Appdelegate should be static . Otherwise both the objects would be diffrent and its consequences would be undefined. I have never seen someone calling init / alloc on appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

Create a static reference of Appdelegate and declare NSStrings as class variables in Appdelegate

Put this is appdelegate

```
+(Appdelegate*)getAppdelegate{
     return self
}
```

and then in your viewcontroller 
do  appdelegate.string1 = string1 and so on ..
you can also encapsulate these objects in an Array and pass them to appdelegate .

The idea is to get a static reference of Appdelegate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the shared object of the appdelegate class for the similar cases.

in the appdelegate class declare global object as

```
#define UIAppDelegate ((MyAppDelegateClass *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

By declaring this, from any class that imports your AppDelegate class can use this shared object of AppDelegate class.

Then is you have three property declared in AppDelegate as

```
@interface MyAppDelegateClass : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
   NSString   *string1;
   NSString   *string2;
   NSString   *string3;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString  string1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString  string2;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString  string3;

@end
```

Then in the AppDelegate Implementation

```
@implementation MyAppDelegateClass

@synthesize string1;
@synthesize string2;
@synthesize string3;

@end
```

In the class from where you need to send the strings to AppDelegate use like below
You need to import AppDelegate class first

```
#import "MyAppDelegateClass.h"

@interface MyCustomSenderClass : UIViewController

@end
```

And in the implementation

```
@implementation MyCustomSenderClass

- (void) sendStringsToAppDelegate
{
   UIAppDelegate.string1 = myString1;
   UIAppDelegate.string2 = myString2;
   UIAppDelegate.string3 = myString3;
}

@end
```

Thus you can directly set a value to the AppDelegate from any class imports your AppDelegate class.

I think this helps you.